# Pointer to object error C++

Tags: c++, windows, object, pointers, reference

I wrote a simple c++ program in which I need to get user that is logged in.
I have a main function and in this main function I call another function that gets the users name.
The problem is that if I call it from the main I get this error
"The expression must have a pointer to object!"

Here is my code:

```
void getUsername(wchar_t &user_name);

int main()
{
  wchar_t user_name;
  getUsername(user_name);

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
```

}

Here is the function that gets the user name

```
void getUsername(wchar_t &user_name)
{


  user_name[UNLEN + 1];
  DWORD size = UNLEN + 1; 
  GetUserName((TCHAR*)user_name, &size);


}
```

The error occurs at user_name[UNLEN+1];
What should I change?

Comment: your `user_name` is char rather than string. you need to pass pointer to char, not char. change it to `wchar_t * user_name;` in the declaration, and to `void getUsername(wchar_t * user_name)` in the function prototype and definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs, because you simply have a syntax error in your code. I guess what you are trying to do is:

```
wchar_t user_name[ULEN + 1];
```

But besides that, you have more problems in your code. `wchar_t` alone represents just a single character. Now look what you are trying to do:

- You create a variable user_name, which is *a single unicode character*
- You pass it to the function *by reference*
- You cast it to `TCHAR*`, so you tell the compiler, that *contents* of this variable *is* a pointer to memory (which it is not)
- You call GetUserName with invalid data, which will surely result in segfault.

Your code *probably* should look like the following (I don't know semantics of `GetUserName` function):

```
void getUsername(wchar_t * user_name);

int main()
{
  wchar_t user_name[ULEN + 1];
  getUsername(user_name);

  // system("PAUSE");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}

void getUsername(wchar_t * user_name)
{
  DWORD size = UNLEN + 1; 
  GetUserName((TCHAR*)user_name, &size);
}
```

**Bonus info**

Guess, what will happen, if someone puts a file `PAUSE.bat` in the same folder as your program with command `format C: /yes` inside?

Comment: unfortunatly formating the system partition while windows is running it is no valid operation. quote from `format` documentation: "Note: of you're in Windows or files on the hard drive are in use this command will not work. "

Comment: I am realatively new to C++ so I did not know that one (if possible) should not use system("anything")
Thanky you for the advice